# Why can't I get the XML document from this link, and why in the string i can get all tag brackets become quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, html

I' m working on an assignment that requires me to get data from the URL http://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire ; specifically, the contents of the `<quote>` and `<author>` tags.

To do this I use a `XMLHttpRequest`; problem is, if I set `xhr.responseType = 'document'` (or if I use `xhr.responseXML` ), the variable I try to put the request in becomes `null`.

If I use `xhr.responseText`, I get the correct representation of the site in string form, and I could solve the problem working with that, but that's not how I'm intended to do it. I tried to parse the string into a XML document, but in the string I get from `xhr.responseText` every `<>` bracket is replaced with a `"`, causing the parsing to produce an incorrect XML document.

Please help me solve one of these two problems, either getting the XML document or the string in the correct XML syntax, thank you very much.

```js
var doc;
var x;           

function submit() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // here adding xhr.responseType = 'document' doesn' t change the outcome
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            doc = xhr.responseXML;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('get', 'http://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire', true);
    xhr.send();
}

function trial(){
    x = doc.getElementsByTagName("quote")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //by this point doc is null, so I get an error here
    console.log( x );
}
```

```html
<h5>Press to see the quote of the day:</h5>
<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="submit()">
<!-- the first button fetches the data from the URL -->
<input type="submit" value="Trial" onclick="trial()">
<!-- the second one is supposed to show on console the quote -->
```

Comment: I see the response is sent with header `Content-Type: application/json;` This seems to indicate the server is not sending back the correct content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's interesting that if you send `Accept` request header like this

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml")
```

then it responses as `XML`.

```js
var doc;
var x;           

function submit() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // here adding xhr.responseType = 'document' doesn' t change the outcome
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            doc = xhr.responseXML;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('get', 'http://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    xhr.send();
}

function trial(){
    x = doc.getElementsByTagName("quote")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //by this point doc is null, so I get an error here
    console.log( x );
}
```

```html
<h5>Press to see the quote of the day:</h5>
<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="submit()">
<!-- the first button fetches the data from the URL -->
<input type="submit" value="Trial" onclick="trial()">
<!-- the second one is supposed to show on console the quote -->
```